# What is the EGT probe output tolerance?

Tags: turbofan, measurement, egt

What is the 'average' or general tolerance (+/-) for EGT probes output on a 'typical' commercial turbofan engine?

Answer (score 4):

It is much more complex than you can imagine. I found a master thesis entitled [Investigation of Sensor Faults in a Gas Turbine](https://webthesis.biblio.polito.it/24135/1/tesi.pdf) of Politecnico di Torino, studying the CFM56 turbofan.

It states that thermocouples used in engines have an accuracy of 0.25% of the full scale. In the particular case of the thesis, they analyzed two different type of thermocouples:

> This thermocouple type presents an accuracy of ± 2.2°C or 0.75% for category 2, while accuracy of ± 1°C or 0.4% for category 1.

However, this is just the sensor itself. The entire thesis discussed about inaccuracies when considering the whole chain (position, etc.) that may be also > 10 °C (see Table 4.1).